# Multiple version of spring-cloud-kubernetes jar

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, fabric8, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am  really confused in jars present in spring-cloud-kubernetes landscape.

This page mentions 2 flavours of each jar, when to use which
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes#2-starters

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

One version is provided by fabric8 directly
https://github.com/fabric8io/spring-cloud-kubernetes#discoveryclient-for-kubernetes

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
    <version>${latest.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

There is one more jar which i dont find managed by spring-cloud-parent project. How to track its upgrade when we are upgrading our spring-boot project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```